# in rails, where is right place to put methods that need to be available 'anywhere'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper

I have lots of little utility methods (such as for reformatting or parsing simple objects like strings) I have been putting in ApplicationHelper.

However, ApplicationHelper methods apparently cannot be accessed by class methods in a model.

There is a workaround, which is to sprinkle thoughout my project:

```
include ApplicationHelper # needed to use apphelper method in instance method
extend ApplicationHelper # needed to use apphelper method in class method
```

and it seems to work. But it seems like a kludge.

Is there a better place to put utility methods so they can be accessed from anywhere in my project - view, controller method, model instance metho, model class method?

Comment: are you monkeypatching core classes like String? or are these domain-specific changes? (like formatting an address) Just trying to get an idea of whether these are really 'everywhere' methods or really just model-related but want to be accessed everywhere. Would it be possible to see a few example methods? That might help direct the conversation.

Comment: we work a lot with phone numbers, for example, and have quite a few methods to sanitize them according to some custom requirements

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what `lib/` is for. I have a file at `lib/deefour.rb` with

```
require "deefour/core_ext"

module Deefour; end
```

I put custom methods in `lib/deefour/helpers.rb`

```
module Deefour
  module Helpers
    extend self

    def some_method
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

and core monkey patches in `lib/deefour/core_ext.rb`

```
class String
  def my_custom_string_method(str)
    # ...
  end
end
```

In `config/initializers/deefour.rb` I put

```
require "deefour"
```

In your `config/application.rb` make sure you have

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib"]
```

Finally, in `ApplicationController` *(for controllers)*, `ApplicationHelper` *(for views)*, and wherever else I need it *(ie. a specific model here and there)* I simply do

```
include ::Deefour::Helpers
```

Comment: one thing -- in your example for config/initializers/deefour.rb I think it needs to be 'include' not 'require'

Comment: No, most definitely not. I suggest reading up on the difference between `require` and `include` in Ruby. In this case I am *not* trying to include the contents of a specific module (it's classes/methods) into the application scope --- I am trying to load the **file**, making the Module itself available for use within other files in the application.