# Rails3: access request.host from within a Mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer, helper

I'm trying to access `request.host` (well, ideally `host_with_port`) from a Mailer in Rails. The actually call to request.host is in a Helper:

```
#/app/helpers/confirmations_helper
module ConfirmationsHelper
  def email_confirm_url(token)
    "http://#{request.host_with_port}/confirm/#{token}" # failure: undefined method
  end
end

#/app/mailers/user_mailer
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "email@domain.com"

  add_template_helper(ConfirmationsHelper) #get access to helpers/confirmations_helper.rb

  def email_confirmation(user)
    @user = user
    @url = "http://www.domain.com/"
    mail(to: user.email, subject: "Email Confirmation")
  end
end

#config/environments/development.rb
...
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "localhost:3000" }
```

Error I'm getting is:

```
 ActionView::Template::Error:
   undefined method `host' for nil:NilClass
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ActionView::Template::Error:
  undefined method `host' for nil:NilClass
```

This is telling you that `request` is `nil`. This is because outside of the scope of your controller *(ie. in a class extending `ActionMailer::Base`)* `request` doesn't exist.

You need to pass the `request` object or just the part you need *(`request.host_with_port`)* to the mailer like you do other data like `user` in your `email_confirmation`.

---

So you have a create method with something like this

```
def create
  @user = User.new

  @user.assign_attributes(params[:user])
  @user.save

  @user.send_email_confirmation
end
```

Inside your `User` model you have a `send_email_confirmation` method like this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def send_email_confirmation
    UserMailer.email_confirmation(self).deliver
  end
```

Your mailer's `email_confirmation` looks like

```
def email_confirmation(user)
  @user = user
  @url = "http://www.domain.com/"
  mail(to: user.email, subject: "Email Confirmation")
end
```

Making the request to the mailer from your **model** is not the best idea; you should keep a cleaner separation of concerns. This is part of your problem and why you are finding unwanted complexity when trying to pass something like `request` from your controller action into the mailer template.

What I might suggest is creating a worker class. **[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13888409/in-rails-where-is-right-place-to-put-methods-that-need-to-be-available-anywher/13888438#13888438)** I explain how to setup classes in `lib/` - the same concept can be applied to something like a `lib/your_app/workers/user.rb`.

You could have the following in this class

```
module YourApp
  module Workers
    module User
      extend self

      def create!(params, options{})
        options.reverse_merge! host: ""

        user = User.new

        user.assign_attributes(params)
        user.save

        UserMailer.email_confirmation(user, host).deliver

        user
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Your controller action could then simply be

```
def create
  @user = ::YourApp::Worker::User.create!(params[:user], host: request.host_with_port)
end
```

Your mailer method can now look like

```
def email_confirmation(user, host)
  @user = user
  token = "" # define token somehow
  @url = "#{host}/confirm/#{token}"
  mail(to: user.email, subject: "Email Confirmation")
end
```

Finally, you can remove `send_email_confirmation` from your model as well as the `email_confirm_url` method from your helper since they're no longer used. Two things to note

- my example above doesn't include anything in the way of validations/error-checks
- my example makes an assumtion about where `token` is being defined and used

As you can see, by introducing this 'worker' class, there is a clean separation of functionality without duplication.

Comment: I'm missing something. UserController#create calls `@user.send_email_confirmation` in the model which in turn calls `UserMailer.email_confirmation(self).deliver` which is where we'd set up the instance variables (`@user`, etc.) for the actual mailer. But there is no access to the `request` object from here. Or from the model. and instance variables back in the controller seem to be unavailable in model & mailer as well... So, must I really tack on the `request`, which I only seem to be able to access in the Controller, through all these method calls? seems clumsy...but what do i know.

Comment: I updated my answer. I hope this helps you understand an alternative approach to this that I feel is 'cleaner'.

Answer (score 10):

Use

```
 ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host]
```

in your Mailer to access the configured host in in config/environments/
I believe, this is the easiest way.